# close bootstrap confirmation when clicking anywhere outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-confirmation

I am using the bootstrap confirmation plugin.  I am attempting to close all confirmations if a click occurs anywhere outside of the confirmation. unfornately it is closing all the time on any click.

```
$('html').on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest("[data-toggle='confirmation']").length === 0) {
    $("[data-toggle='confirmation']").confirmation('hide');
  }
```

here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/zukdokpb/270/

Answer (score 1):

<s>You just need to target the button instead of `html`:</s>

```
$("#mybutton").on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest("[data-toggle='confirmation']").length === 0) {
    $("[data-toggle='confirmation']").confirmation('hide');
  }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zukdokpb/271/

It should do it for you if you use the `data-popout`attribute ([new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zukdokpb/276/))
I see that you did that on the first button but not on the second. Adding it should fix the default functionality. Then `$(e.target).closest("[data-toggle='confirmation']").length` returns `0` unless you actually click on the original buttons, so it was hiding the popup on all other clicks.

html:

```
<a href="#Delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" title="Deseja realmente excluir o projeto?" data-toggle="confirmation" data-singleton="true" data-placement="top" data-popout="true"><span title="Excluir o projeto">Excluir</span></a>

<button type="button" class="btn" ng-show="patient.Archived" data-toggle="confirmation" data-singleton="true" data-popout="true">
  Archived
</button>
```

js:

```
$('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({
    btnOkLabel: "&nbsp;Sim",
    btnCancelLabel: "&nbsp;Não"
});
```

Comment: that does not work if you click on either button a confirmation pops up if you click away from the button/s the confirmation does not dismiss. why are you using ID? there are mulitple confirmations with different IDs. and one is a button and one is a link – Bryan Dellinger 30 secs ago   edit

Comment: It works for me? In the fiddle you would still need to click inside the html of the "results" area which would only be above and around the popover - clicking below it is basically another document in the context of this fiddle. I forgot about the other button but you could use a common class the same way. But I updated my answer with a different solution.